# What is the dimension of the space of commutators?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $$S:=\{AB-BA:A,B\in M_3(\mathbb R)\}\leq M_3(\mathbb R)$$ Find
>   $\dim S$.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Notice that the matrices $AB - BA$ all have zero trace.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677496/subspace-of-the-real-matrices-generated-by-the-matrices-of-the-form-ab-ba

Comment: Also $\underline{\text{traceless matrices}}$ :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/729796/721644$$$$ https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1028990168

Comment: Look at the number of free parameters under the constraint $\mathrm{tr}(s) = 0$ for $s \in S$