# $XY-YX = J_4-I_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> To find square matrices $X$ and $Y$ of order $4$ such that $$XY-YX = J_4-I_4,$$ where $J_4$ is the matrix of all ones and $I$ is the identity matrix.

There is an article "A Note on Matrix Solutions to A = XY - YX" by Charles R. Johnson saying that such matrices exist when $\mathrm{trace}(A) = 0$. Here the trace condition is satisfied, but how to find matrices $X$ and $Y$... there is no explicit method.

Can someone shed some light? Thank You.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3835642/81360)

Answer (score 2):

This works already for certain diagonal matrices $X$, e.g., set $X=\operatorname{diag}(0,1,2,3)$. Then $XY-YX=J_4-I_4$ is equivalent to a system of linear equations in the coefficients of $Y$. All solutions for $Y$ are given by
$$
Y=\frac{1}{6}\begin{pmatrix} a & -6 & -3 & -2 \cr
6 & b & -6 & -3 \cr
3 & 6 & c & -6 \cr
2 & 3 & 6 & d
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
for arbitrary $a,b,c,d\in K$.

You, or someone else already asked this for $3\times 3$-matrices, see below. Now it should be clear how to generalize to all $n$.

Reference:
[Finding matrices $X,Y$ such that $XY - YX = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835642/finding-matrices-x-y-such-that-xy-yx-left-beginsmallmatrix011-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)